# Session/state in java ee JAX-RS with EJBs?

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, ejb, jax-rs, jaas

Say that we want a rest-based shopping cart completely realized with XHR calls on the client-browser side and as a rest service implemented with java-ee on the server side. We use JAAS for security.

Client will log in, do shopping, close browser, come back later to continue shopping with his state remembered without the need to do login again.

**How exactly is his state kept?**

Below is a nominal stateful bean for the cart, it must be injected in a REST resource that will be the interface between client and business logic:

```
@Stateful
public class ClientCart{

    @Resource private SessionContext ctx;
    private List<String> items; //contains a list of products

    @PostConstruct
    private void createCart(){
        /*
        init stuff like db connection...
        get name of user with ctx.getCallerPrincipa()
        check if user had items in cart in the db
        if there were items, create a list: items = new LinkedList()<>;
        else: populate items with whatever was in db
        */
    }

    public List getItems(){ /* return the cart... */ }

    public void addItem(String item){ /*do a items.add(item); */}

    @PrePassivate
    private void maintenanceOnSleep(){
        /*
        Called when the server decided to suspend this instance due to long time of inactivity - when user close browser, etc...
        Does clean up tasks like closing a db connection
        */
    }

    @PostActivate
    private void maintenanceOnActivate(){
        /*
        Opposite of @PrePassivete - open the db connection...
        */
    }

    @Remove
    public void logout(){ /* nothing in here... */ }

    @PreDestroy
    public void cleanUP(){
        /* called when error happens or logout() is explicitly called, will send purge instance vars like items to db and close connections.
    }

}
```

Now how do i make the rest resource? As rest is request scoped, i can't inject the stateful bean...

```
@Path("/shop")
public class ShoppingCart{

    @GET
    @Path("/login/{user}/{pass}
    public void (@Context HttpServletRequest rq, @PathParam("user") String u, @PathParam("pass") String p {

        /*
        we do programmatic logins with rq.login(u, p); ... and then what happens? :) 
        */

    }

}
```

Comment: Isn't the whole rest-idea about statelessness on server side? A request has no session attached at all. Of course, there is data stored/cached on the server but a shopping cart... Either let the client handle it or if you want it to be more sticky, persist it. From my experience rest and stateful session beans have different backgrounds and shouldn't be mixed for common use cases.

Comment: Yes, it is stateless by concept. But it's not a commandment that will put you in hell if you break it. This was just a thought. Thanks for input.